# How to email a message to a specific email address from Moodle dashboard

Tags: email, moodle

There are many plugins to send message in Moodle(v2.9) but this is only for internal messaging system. But i need to send email outside of Moodle user(By specific email address) from dashboard. Please suggest me any plugin or how to send email to specific email address from Moodle(v2.9) Dashboard

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking for. Can you please re-write the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moodle is learning management system and its boundary is limited to its users, so you cannot send email messages to outside of its users. That's why there is no plugin for this purpose.

Use email messaging system for this purpose.